# Entity Framework 6.0 Multilevel joins group

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity

**Environment:** EF 6 SQL 2012

**Lazy Loading Disabled**

I have a Service Request table which is having 1 to many relationship with Phase table which in turn is having one to many relationship with Tasks table. I m fetching record from Service request table and in order to compute NextActionDate in Service request, i need to account for Task dates.

This is the query which i have written without the highlighted one, it returns one record as expected, but if i remove the highlighted line, i m getting many records.. In the specific case, a single Service request was having 6 Phases and each phase is having multiple Tasks.. Could some guide me on how to approach this?

[image]

```
var servRequest = (from srDet in SRDB.ServRequestDetails
                               from srCustReqRef in srDet.ServRequest.ServReqCustReqRefs
                               from srOpSys in srDet.ServRequest.ServReqOpSys
                               from srOpSysDet in srOpSys.ServReqOpSysDetails
                               //from srPh in srDet.ServRequest.ServReqPhases
                               //from srTask in srPh.ServReqTasks


                               where srDet!=null && srCustReqRef.CustRequestID == 1 && srDet.IsActiveRow == true
                                && srCustReqRef.ServRequestID == 1 && srOpSysDet.IsActiveRow==true


                               select new ServReqDTO()
                               {
                                   ServRequestID = srDet.ServRequestID,
                                   Requestor = srDet.HRUser_Requestor.DisplayName,
                                   RequestorID = srDet.RequestorID,
                                   SubmittedDate = srDet.ServRequest.SubmitDateTime,
                                   ServRequestTypeID = srDet.ServRequestTypeID,
                                   ServRequestType = srDet.ServRequestType.ServRequestTypeVal,
                                   TargetDate = srDet.TargetCompletionDate,
                                   OS = srOpSysDet.OperatingSystem.OperatingSystemVal,
                                   OSID = srOpSysDet.OperatingSystem.OperatingSystemID,
                                   //TaskFollowupDates = srTask.ServReqTaskDetails.Where(i => i.IsActiveRow == true).Select(task => task.TaskFollowUpDate).ToList(),
                                   //TaskEndDates = srTask.ServReqTaskDetails.Where(i => i.IsActiveRow == true).Select(task => task.TaskEndDate).ToList(),
                                   //TaskStartDates = srTask.ServReqTaskDetails.Where(i => i.IsActiveRow == true).Select(task => task.TaskStartDate).ToList(),
                                   NextActionDate = null,
                                   ServReqStatus = srDet.ServReqStatusType.ServReqStatusTypeVal,
                                   ServReqStatusTypeID = srDet.ServRequestTypeID
                               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to get, but have a look at SelectMany() http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/

Comment: @SteveGreene I would like to retrieve a single row from Service request detail table. One of the column in that should be list of dates from Task table. As i explained in my post, Service request is related to Phase through one-many relationship which in turn is related to task trhough one-many relationship. In my query, for each matching record, i m getting new row.